# Quick and dirty way to solve/kill memory increses on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-leaks

I have an app running on Heroku with a few thousand visitors per day. I do not update it very often as it runs well anyway. Recently, however, I started getting memory increases in a way I have never had before. I am 98% sure it does not have to do with any changes in the code that I have done, as I have not done anything to the code in quite a while. I know from experience that tracing down memory issues is extremely difficult and time-consuming - and at the moment I don't have the time to do it.

Considering the fact that I get this stair-case increase in memory over time (over the course of a few hours) once a day, is there a quick and dirty way of just restarting the server once it starts doing so, so it won't slow down the server for those hours? Like

```
RestartApp if ServerMemory > 500 Mb
```

or the likes of it?

[image: Memory usage on Herou]

I am running ruby 2.4.7 (is that likely an issue in terms of memory increases?) and Rails 4.2.10

Comment: Did you look into https://github.com/schneems/puma_worker_killer?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that one. Thanks!

Comment: Np, have a good weekend! ;)